# Counting unique elements in Scheme

Tags: count, scheme, unique, element, distinct

Write a recursive Scheme procedure count-dist elements that takes a list with duplicate elements and returns the number of distinct elements in the list.

This is my code, but it is not working correctly. Please help! Thanks!!

```
(define (count-dist-elements lis)   
  (cond
    ((null? lis) 0)
    ((null? (cdr lis))0)
    ((member (car lis)(cdr lis)))
     (else(+ 1(count-dist-elements (cdr lis))))))
```

p/s: let it be (count-dist-elements '(1 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 8 9))

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your difficulties, but your code is not indented quite correctly. If this reflects how it actually looks and isn't just a glitch on entering it into Stack Overflow, may I strongly recommend that you get into the habit of *always* indenting and spacing your code with care? This will make it easier to read (for yourself and others) and will make some mistakes harder not to notice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're getting pretty close.

- What happens when you pass your function a list with one element? What should your function return in this case?
- What about a two-element list with the same element (eg. `(5 5)`)? Does your function return a sensible value?

Comment: if one element, then the count would be 1.
if is a list with 2 same elements, it will be 1 too. But if I want to pass a longer list in there. What else am I missing in the code?

Comment: @Melissa: Your analysis is correct, however your function doesn't actually work that way. You will need to fix your function.

Answer (score 0):

First: Why are you returning zero in the `(null? (cdr lis))` case?

Second: What do you think your code returns in the case where the first element also occurs later in the list? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

```
 (define (count-dist-elements lst dist-elems count)
   (cond ((null? lst) count)
         ((member (car lst) dist-elems)
          (count-dist-elements (cdr lst) dist-elems count))
         (else
          (count-dist-elements (cdr lst)
                               (cons (car lst) dist-elems)
                               (+ 1 count)))))
```

`(count-dist-elements '(a b b c) '() 0)` ==> `3`

`(count-dist-elements '(1 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 8 9) '() 0)` ==> `9`

Or, if you want it recursive and not iterative (and, it has to use a function call like the one shown),

```
(define (count-dist-elements lst . dist-elems)
  (let ((dist-elems (if (null? dist-elems) '() (car dist-elems))))
    (cond ((null? lst) 0)
          ((member (car lst) dist-elems)
           (count-dist-elements (cdr lst) dist-elems))
          (else
           (+ 1 (count-dist-elements (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) dist-elems)))))))
```

Gives the same results.

`(count-dist-elements '(1 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 8 9))` ==> `9`